# How to make image display follow the focus in image-dired thumbnail buffer

Tags: image-dired

There are two buffers in `image-dired`, one is the thumbnail buffer `*image-dired*`, the other is the displayed image buffer `*image-dired-display-image*`.

When I type <kbd>return</kbd> on an image thumbnail, the focus is switched to the displayed image buffer.

Is there a setting that will make the focus stay in the thumbnail buffer?  What about making the displayed image buffer follow the focus in the thumbnail buffer without hitting return?

Edit: Turns out the culprit is shackle. If you use it, the default behaviour is restored with:

```
(setq shackle-rules
'(("\\`\\*image-dired.*?\\*\\'" :regexp t :select nil)
  (image-dired-thumbnail-mode :select nil)
  (image-dired-image-display-mode :select nil))
  shackle-default-rule '(:select t))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I type return on an image thumbnail, the focus is switched to the displayed image buffer. Is there a setting that will make the focus stay in the thumbnail buffer?

What you're asking for is the *default* behaviour so far as I can see (when running `image-dired` in both emacs 24.5 and 25.2). You should be able to confirm that by running `emacs -Q`.

> What about making the displayed image buffer follow the focus in the thumbnail buffer without hitting return?

If you just want to cycle through the images, then:

- <kbd>SPC</kbd> runs the command `image-dired-display-next-thumbnail-original`
- <kbd>DEL</kbd> (translated from <kbd><backspace></kbd> in my case) runs the command `image-dired-display-previous-thumbnail-original`

As always, use <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> to view help on the modes and keybindings for the current buffer.

---

> When I run image-dired in a dired buffer, all files are marked, how to disable that behavior and mark the files in the thumbnail view manually?

Mark the files in dired and call <kbd>M-x</kbd> `image-dired-display-thumbs` instead of `image-dired`

That command is bound to <kbd>C-t</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> by default.

Type <kbd>C-t</kbd><kbd>C-h</kbd> in a dired buffer to see other image/thumbnail-related bindings under that same prefix.

Comment: When I run image-dired in a dired buffer, all files are marked, how to disable that behavior and mark the files in the thumbnail view manually?